# Trigger a function on key up on any input

Tags: javascript

I want a javascript function to be triggered on key up on any input box. I tried using `getElementsByTagName.onkeyup` but it didn't work. Along with the solution please send a working jsfiddle. I don't want `document.getElementById` or `onkeyup="function()"` as there are many input boxes. It wont look tidy. I even tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input').onkeyup(function(){
calculate();
})
})
```

I also want a function that will add 0 to the value of each input on window.onload.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TMtKM/1/) There is no `onkeyup` event in jQuery tru to change to `keyup`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input').keyup(function(){
      calculate();
      })
    })
```

[.**keyup()**](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('keyup', 'input', function() {
        calculate();
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DWhs7/)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.onkeyup = function () {
  if (document.activeElement.tagName.toUpperCase() !== 'input') return;
  // do sth. here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the keyup part:

http://jsfiddle.net/pwqx7/

```
$(function() {
$('input').bind('keyup', function() {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
});
```